# How do I find administrators of a Document Library with custom permissions?

Tags: document-library, permissions

I have a document library which does not inherit the site's permissions ('Custom permissions' is set).

How do I find out who has administrator permissions to this library, using C#?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you're looking for is [SPList.DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436062.aspx)

Here is a slightly modified version of the example on that page, which may do what you need:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://your/site/here"))
{
   SPBasePermissions perms = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;

   string listUrl = site.RootWeb.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "Your Document Library Name";
   SPList list = site.RootWeb.GetList(listUrl);

   // Be sure the current user has permission to check permissions.
   if (site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
   {
      foreach (SPGroup group in site.RootWeb.Groups)
      {
         foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
         {
            // Check another user's permissions.
            bool hasPermission = list.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, perms);
            Console.WriteLine("{0, -5}  {1}", hasPermission, user.LoginName);
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Never put a using around a site's RootWeb, it will cause exceptions. Pretty much the rule of thumb is: if you "own" (i.e. created) the disposable object, then dispose it. If it is created by the SharePoint API, don't

Comment: @Colin: Good call. I should've spotted that error in the example. I've updated the code accordingly.